# How to insert a null-value to the database in C# without using parameters?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Using SQL parameters, I could insert a `NULL` value to the database using this sort of C# code:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (@value)";
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add("@value", DBNull.Value);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Not using parameters is usually considered to be bad practice, because of SQL-Injection and some other reasons. But, I am curious to know if there is a way to do so without using them. Something like this:

```
var nullValue = DBNull.value;
string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (" + nullValue + ")";
```

or even:

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (\\NULL\\)";
```

or whatever. Thanks.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: I do not face a problem. I am just curious. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Uhmm yes. You could do that, if you are certain that the column should always be NULL, then you could simply write the SQL statement in a full string, like this.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (NULL)";
```

If you take input from a user, then NEVER do this, this is exactly how you get injected.

```
var nullValue = DBNull.value;
string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (" + nullValue + ")";
```

The injection would happen if the `nullValue` contained something like the string `NULL); DROP TABLE table_name`. Where the `NULL);` just completes your own SQL allowing for more SQL code to wreak havoc on your data.

The first rule of web development. NEVER EVER trust user data. Use parameters.

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("connection_String"))
{
    string query = "INSERT INTO table_name (column_name) VALUES (@val1)";

    using(SqlCommand inputQuery = new SqlCommand(query))
    {
        inputQuery.Connection = openCon;
        inputQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val1", DBNull.Value);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            int recordsAffected = inputQuery.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException)
        {
            // error here
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this..

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue(
"@ProductName",
// this requires a cast as ?: must return the same type
String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(productName)
    ? (object)DBNull.Value
    : (object)productName
);
```

Comment: Your code uses parameters... I want to know how to do this without using them. Thank. :)